# API call is not triggering process builder

Tags: api

Issue: Process Builder which creates related records, Journeys, is not firing from API calls.

Setup: I have a process builder, let's call it PB1, where based on the criteria of our custom object Receivable, run the flow.

From the SFDC user interface I click edit and update the fields as below and things fire just fine.

- Status = Active
- Payment Start Date = Today()
- Original Amount = 4000

However when we are doing an API call it's not working, nor from the Execute Anonymous.  This is what I'm doing to test.

```
Payswag__Receivable__c var_r=[select id from Payswag__Receivable__c 
   where Name = 'sl1']; 
var_r.Status__c='Active';
var_r.loan_payment_start_date__c=date.newInstance(2016,11,10);
var_r.Original_Amount__c=4000;
update var_r;
```

**So the question is: Why does the UI behave as expected however the API calls do not?**

Comment: Is it set to only evaluate when the values change? If so you ui updates would make it not run on subsequent API update

Comment: Eric - I'm assuming you're talking about this setting: http://screencast.com/t/YgjhG7PSHKw (Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?)  That is false.  I'm not sure I understand your last comment.  'my ui updates would make *it* not run on subsequent API updates?

Comment: an Update: our journeys are being created, however the incorrect journeys are being created.  Which now points to the PB since that's where the Journey Flow is being called from.  Again - if we edit the Receivable from the UI it creates the proper journeys. However when updating the Receivable from the API, the incorrect journey is being created.

Comment: Update: I think there is a bug with the process builder criteria.
In our process builder the Receivable object, a child of Account, is the starting sObject.  In the criteria of nodes we are traversing up to the account and checking a field, Account.Balance__c.  It appears the process builder is treating this field as NULL or Zero for that is why it was firing one node all the time (we had balance < 500).  When we changed it to be greater than 0 and less than 500 it never entered that node.  That confirms my thought of the process builder is unable to traverse up and check a number field.

Comment: -- Continued comment from above update.  Again this is for only the API, where as when use the UI of salesforce everything works perfectly.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. The process builder works fine via the UI but not when a record is updated via the API. When the update is completed by the API, this does meet the Process Builder criteria however, the action does not fire.